# Extendable REST-Client - follow-up

Tags: c#, generics, rest, extension-methods, fluent-interface

My [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187717/extendable-rest-client) `RestClient` wasn't disposing a lot of resources. I've fixed it (hopefully without introducing new issues) and because a few new patterns emerged I did a lot of refactoring and simplified a few things - in fact I was able to remove more then a hundered lines of code.

It looks like there is a lot of code left but the only complex part is the `RestClient`. Other classes are only data or contain mostly one-liner convenience extensions.

---

#### RestClient

I reduces the main interface to just one method for invoking http-methods. Details are *hidden* by the `HttpMethodContext` that provides the required flexibility.

```
[PublicAPI]
public interface IRestClient
{
    Task<T> InvokeAsync<T>(HttpMethod httpMethod, UriDynamicPart uriDynamicPart, HttpMethodContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

[PublicAPI]
public class RestClient : IRestClient
{
    private readonly HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration _defaultHttpRequestHeadersConfiguration;

    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public RestClient(string baseUri, HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration defaultHttpRequestHeadersConfiguration)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri)
        };
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _defaultHttpRequestHeadersConfiguration = defaultHttpRequestHeadersConfiguration;
    }

    public async Task<T> InvokeAsync<T>(HttpMethod httpMethod, UriDynamicPart uriDynamicPart, HttpMethodContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await SendRequestAsync(httpMethod, uriDynamicPart, context, cancellationToken);

        var hasContent = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength > 0 && !(typeof(T) == typeof(object));
        if (hasContent)
        {
            return await response.Content
                .ReadAsAsync<T>(new[] { context.ResponseFormatter }, cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    response.Dispose();
                    return t.Result;
                }, cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            return await Task
                .FromResult(default(T))
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    response.Dispose();
                    return default(T);
                }, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync(HttpMethod method, UriDynamicPart uriDynamicPart, HttpMethodContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, CreateAbsoluteUri(uriDynamicPart)))
        {
            if (!(context.Body is null))
            {
                request.Content = new ObjectContent(context.Body.GetType(), context.Body, context.RequestFormatter);
            }

            _defaultHttpRequestHeadersConfiguration.Apply(request.Headers);
            context.HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration.Apply(request.Headers);

            var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            if (context.EnsureSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }

            return response;
        }
    }

    private Uri CreateAbsoluteUri(string uriDynamicPart)
    {
        return new Uri(_client.BaseAddress, uriDynamicPart);
    }
}
```

I moved the http-methods into extensions:

```
public static class RestClientExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> GetAsync<T>(this IRestClient client, [NotNull] UriDynamicPart uriDynamicPart, [CanBeNull] HttpMethodContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return client.InvokeAsync<T>(HttpMethod.Get, uriDynamicPart, context, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static Task<T> PutAsync<T>(this IRestClient client, [NotNull] UriDynamicPart uriDynamicPart, [CanBeNull] HttpMethodContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return client.InvokeAsync<T>(HttpMethod.Put, uriDynamicPart, context, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static Task<T> PostAsync<T>(this IRestClient client, [NotNull] UriDynamicPart uriDynamicPart, [CanBeNull] HttpMethodContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return client.InvokeAsync<T>(HttpMethod.Post, uriDynamicPart, context, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static Task<T> DeleteAsync<T>(this IRestClient client, [NotNull] UriDynamicPart uriDynamicPart, [CanBeNull] HttpMethodContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return client.InvokeAsync<T>(HttpMethod.Delete, uriDynamicPart, context, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

#### HTTP-Method context

Previously, I had five of these classes (after adding support for other http-methods). They were all so similar that it made more sense to use only a single class with all possible parameters.

```
[PublicAPI]
public class HttpMethodContext
{
    [NotNull]
    public UriDynamicPart UriDynamicPart { get; set; } = new UriDynamicPart();

    [NotNull]
    public HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration { get; set; } = new HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration();

    [CanBeNull]
    public object Body { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public MediaTypeFormatter RequestFormatter { get; set; } = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

    [NotNull]
    public MediaTypeFormatter ResponseFormatter { get; set; } = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

    public bool EnsureSuccessStatusCode { get; set; } = true;
}
```

---

#### Fluent API extensions

Several extensions provide the necessary framework for building concrete requests and calling actions.

The first extension creates an *IResourceContext* for a specific resource - it stores all the necessary data to chain the second and final extension for executing the http-methods.

```
public static class ResourceContextFactory
{
    public static IResourceContext<TResource> ToResource<TResource>(this IRestClient client, string name = null)
    {
        // We get the resource name either from the attribute or the name of the interface without the "I" prefix.
        var resourceName =
            name 
            ?? typeof(TResource)
                .GetCustomAttribute<ResourceNameAttribute>()
                ?.ToString()
            ?? Regex.Replace(typeof(TResource).Name, "^I", string.Empty);

        return (IResourceContext<TResource>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ResourceContext<TResource>), new object[] { client, resourceName });
    }
}

// ReSharper disable once UnusedTypeParameter - The generic argument is used for building strong extensions.
public interface IResourceContext<TResource>
{
    IRestClient Client { get; }

    UriDynamicPart UriDynamicPart { get; }

    HttpMethodContext MethodContext { get; }

    Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    Task<TResult> PutAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    Task<TResult> DeleteAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

[PublicAPI]
public class ResourceContext<TResource> : IResourceContext<TResource>
{
    public ResourceContext([NotNull] IRestClient client, params string[] path)
    {
        Client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
        UriDynamicPart = new UriDynamicPart(path);
    }

    [NotNull]
    public IRestClient Client { get; }

    public UriDynamicPart UriDynamicPart { get; }

    public HttpMethodContext MethodContext { get; } = new HttpMethodContext();

    public Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Client.GetAsync<TResult>(UriDynamicPart, MethodContext, cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task<TResult> PutAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Client.PutAsync<TResult>(UriDynamicPart, MethodContext, cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Client.PostAsync<TResult>(UriDynamicPart, MethodContext, cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task<TResult> DeleteAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Client.DeleteAsync<TResult>(UriDynamicPart, MethodContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

---

#### HTTP-Request-Headers configuration

This new and immutable class allows me to chain http-request-headers configuration for the `RestClient`.

```
public class HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration
{
    private readonly Action<HttpRequestHeaders> _action;

    public HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration(Action<HttpRequestHeaders> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration() : this(_ => { }) { }

    public void Apply(HttpRequestHeaders headers)
    {
        _action(headers);
    }

    public static implicit operator HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration(Action<HttpRequestHeaders> action)
    {
        return new HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration(action);
    }

    public static HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration operator +(HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration configuration, Action<HttpRequestHeaders> action)
    {
        return configuration._action.Append(action);
    }
}
```

---

#### Exmaples

I implement resource APIs by creating a marker interface that stands for a resource I want to access - they have the same name as the controller (without the *I*). This creates a strong context that I can now use to write extensions for invoking actions on the web-service.

(I was also thinking of generating them with a *T4* script later.)

> ```
> public interface ITransactions { }
>
> public static class TransactionsClient
> {
>     public static IResourceContext<ITransactions> Transactions(this IRestClient client)
>     {
>         return client.ToResource<ITransactions>();
>     }
> }
>
> public static class TransactionClientExtensions
> {
>     public static Task<Transaction> NewTransactionAsync(this IResourceContext<ITransactions> resource)
>     {
>         return resource.GetAsync<Transaction>(CancellationToken.None);
>     }
> }
> ```

In my application I first create a default header customization and use it to initialize the client:

> ```
> var configureDefaultRequestHeaders =
>     new HttpRequestHeadersConfiguration()
>         .Clear()
>         .AcceptJson()
>         .AddRange(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
>         {
>             ["X-Test"] = new[] { "development" }
>         });
>
> var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:54245/api/", configureDefaultRequestHeaders);
> ```

then I call the extensions to acces a resource:

> ```
> var t = await client.Transactions().NewTransactionAsync();
> ```

Should I want to customize the request for a specific call, I would do it just after calling `.Transactions()`. Here I can chain extensions for adding other headers etc.

---

What do you think of this client? Is it intuitive and easy to use? Is it easy to extend?

*I deliberately did not any null-checks (yet).*

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ResourceContext<TResource>), new object[] { client, resourceName })` instead of `new ResourceContext<TResource>(...)`? I've been staring at it for a few minutes and it appears that the constructor should be directly accessible and then no need for a cast. I just woke up and am groggy so I might be missing something here, otherwise I'd point this out as part of an answer. Also what prevents calling of `ToResource` with a non-Attributed non-interface type (or a class that legitimately begins with the letter I)?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 You're right, I can use the constructor directly. Thanks for pointing this out. There was a reason before but there is none anymore and apparently I didn't notice it. I used a `new` on some `T` so I wasn't able to just `new` it with parameters. Now that I have only one type the `Activator` is no longer necessary. I'm not sure if I understand you question about `ToResource`. You mean it's not guarded and can produce invalid results? I haven't given too much thought to it yet and I'm hoping that I'm not going to break by sticking  to my own convention ;-)

Comment: Has this ended up as a library somewhere? It's very similar to Flurl.Http

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper you can find the latest code on my github [here](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/tree/dev/Reusable.Teapot) and [this](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/tree/dev/Reusable.Tests/src/Teapot) test shows how I use it. Indeed, it's similar to Flurl but I didn't like it so I wrote my own tool.