# C# REST / Http Client Abstraction

Tags: c#, http, dependency-injection, rest, interface

I have a REST library. These are the abstractions. Have I missed anything that a developer would need to use this in a dependency injection / IoC Container scenario? Anything that bothers you about this?

[All Code Here](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net/tree/develop)

```
public interface IRestClient
{
    IRestHeadersCollection DefaultRequestHeaders { get; }
    TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }
    Task DeleteAsync(Uri queryString);
    Task DeleteAsync(Uri queryString, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> GetAsync<TReturn>();
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> GetAsync<TReturn>(Uri queryString);
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> GetAsync<TReturn>(Uri queryString, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PatchAsync<TReturn, TBody>(TBody body, Uri queryString);
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PatchAsync<TReturn, TBody>(TBody body, Uri queryString, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PostAsync<TReturn, TBody>(TBody body, Uri queryString);
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PostAsync<TReturn, TBody>(TBody body, Uri queryString, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PutAsync<TReturn, TBody>(TBody body, Uri queryString);
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PutAsync<TReturn, TBody>(TBody body, Uri queryString, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public interface IRestClientFactory
{
    IRestClient CreateRestClient(Uri baseUri);
    IRestClient CreateRestClient();
}

public interface IRestHeadersCollection : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
{
    void Add(string name, string value);
    void Add(string name, IEnumerable<string> values);
    void Clear();

    IEnumerable<string> this[string name]
    {
        get;
    }

    bool Contains(string name);
}

public partial interface ISerializationAdapter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Takes an object of Type T and converts it to binary data
    /// </summary>
    Task<byte[]> SerializeAsync<T>(T value);

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes binary data and converts it to an object of type T
    /// </summary>
    Task<T> DeserializeAsync<T>(byte[] data);
}

public interface ITracer
{
    void Trace(HttpVerb httpVerb, Uri baseUri, Uri queryString, byte[] body, TraceType traceType, int? httpStatusCode, IRestHeadersCollection restHeadersCollection);
}

public class RestResponse<TBody> : RestResponse
{
    public TBody Body { get; }

    public RestResponse(TBody body, IRestHeadersCollection restHeadersCollection, int statusCode, object underlyingResponse) : base(restHeadersCollection, statusCode, underlyingResponse)
    {
        Body = body;
    }

    #region Implicit Operator
    public static implicit operator TBody(RestResponse<TBody> readResult)
    {
        return readResult.Body;
    }

    public TBody ToTBody()
    {
        return Body;
    }
    #endregion
}

public class RestResponse
{
    #region Public Properties
    public int StatusCode { get; }
    public object UnderlyingResponse { get; }
    public IRestHeadersCollection Headers { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public RestResponse(IRestHeadersCollection restHeadersCollection, int statusCode, object underlyingResponse)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        UnderlyingResponse = underlyingResponse;
        Headers = restHeadersCollection;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Originally I thought it might be useful to allow task async calls for serialization/deserialization but I've come to think that this is a bit redundant... Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If already coupling to `System.Net` for `HttpStatusCode`, why not use `HttpMethod` instead of custom `HttpVerb` enum? If truly trying to abstract away then why not `int?` for status code?

Comment: Looking at the client implementation you create a new instance of `HttpClient` if one is not provided. This can lead to socket exhaustion.

Comment: @Nkosi nice find. Fixed your first point. Not sure I know what you mean by socket exhaustion... I just did a massive refactor and now the HttpClient has been changed to a HttpClientFactory so it can be implemented to create a new HttpClient in each case. However, the default factory is this and it probably suffers from the problem you mentioned: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net/blob/develop/RestClient.Net/SingletonHttpClientFactory.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IRestClient` looks over-engineered. All of those helper members merge down to one common `Call` which can make the interface much simpler to define.

```
public interface IRestClient {
    IRestHeadersCollection DefaultRequestHeaders { get; }
    string DefaultContentType { get; set; }
    TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }
    Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> SendAsync<TReturn>(RestRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
}
```

The client now simplified to its core features.

The commonly used parameters can be aggregated into a class

```
public class RestRequest {

    public RestRequest() {
    }

    public RestRequest(IRestClient client) : this() {
        var contentType = client.DefaultContentType;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType)) {
            ContentType = contentType;
        }
        var headers = client.DefaultRequestHeaders;
        if (headers != null) {
            foreach (var header in headers) {
                Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    public IRestHeadersCollection Headers { get; } = new RestRequestHeaders();

    public Uri Resource { get; set; }
    public HttpVerb HttpVerb { get; set; } = HttpVerb.Get;
    public string ContentType { get; set; } = "application/json";
    public object Body { get; set; }

    class RestRequestHeaders : HttpHeaders, IRestHeadersCollection {
        public RestRequestHeaders() : base() { }
        public IEnumerable<string> this[string name] => GetValues(name) ?? Array.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

Naming is important here. Change the name to `resource` from `queryString`, which means something different to how it was originally being used with regards to HTTP requests.

Parameter order should also be changed to be more consistent.

Your original call would have looked something like

```
...await client.PostAsync<ReturnObject, BodyObject>(body, "...");
```

with the URI parameter second. When making the request, the first argument should be the resource being called. Everything else can be built up from there

```
...await client.PostAsync<ReturnObject, BodyObject>("...", body);
...await client.PostAsync<ReturnObject, BodyObject>("...", body, token);
//...etc
```

The following extensions allow for the same functionality as before on the `IRestClient` abstraction

```
public static class RestClientExtensions {
    #region Delete
    public static Task DeleteAsync(this IRestClient client, string resource) {
        return client.DeleteAsync(new Uri(resource, UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public static Task DeleteAsync(this IRestClient client, Uri resource) {
        return client.DeleteAsync(resource, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public static Task DeleteAsync(this IRestClient client, Uri resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var request = new RestRequest(client) {
            Resource = resource,
            HttpVerb = HttpVerb.Delete
        };
        return client.SendAsync<object>(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Get
    public static Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> GetAsync<TReturn>(this IRestClient client) {
        var request = new RestRequest(client) {
            HttpVerb = HttpVerb.Get
        };
        return client.SendAsync<TReturn>(request, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public static Task<RestResponse<TResult>> GetAsync<TResult>(this IRestClient client, string resource) {
        try {
            return client.GetAsync<TResult>(new Uri(resource, UriKind.Relative));
        } catch (UriFormatException ufe) {
            if (ufe.Message == "A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.") {
                throw new UriFormatException(Messages.ErrorMessageAbsoluteUriAsString, ufe);
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> GetAsync<TReturn>(this IRestClient client, Uri resource) {
        return client.GetAsync<TReturn>(resource, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public static Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> GetAsync<TReturn>(this IRestClient client, Uri resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var request = new RestRequest(client) {
            Resource = resource
        };
        return client.SendAsync<TReturn>(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Patch
    public static Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PatchAsync<TReturn, TBody>(this IRestClient client, Uri resource, TBody body) {
        return client.PatchAsync<TReturn, TBody>(resource, body, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public static Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PatchAsync<TReturn, TBody>(this IRestClient client, Uri resource, TBody body, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var request = new RestRequest(client) {
            Resource = resource,
            HttpVerb = HttpVerb.Patch,
            Body = body,
        };
        return client.SendAsync<TReturn>(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Post
    public static Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PostAsync<TReturn, TBody>(this IRestClient client, TBody body, Uri querresourceString) {
        return client.PostAsync<TReturn, TBody>(body, querresourceString, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public static Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PostAsync<TReturn, TBody>(this IRestClient client, TBody body, Uri resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var request = new RestRequest(client) {
            Resource = resource,
            HttpVerb = HttpVerb.Post,
            Body = body,
        };
        return client.SendAsync<TReturn>(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Put
    public static Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PutAsync<TReturn, TBody>(this IRestClient client, TBody body, Uri resource) {
        return client.PutAsync<TReturn, TBody>(body, resource, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public static Task<RestResponse<TReturn>> PutAsync<TReturn, TBody>(this IRestClient client, TBody body, Uri resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var request = new RestRequest(client) {
            Resource = resource,
            HttpVerb = HttpVerb.Put,
            Body = body,
        };
        return client.SendAsync<TReturn>(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the this detailed answer. I can definitely see the value here. I don't think I'm going to be able implement this for the V3, but I will digest this over time and see if it fits for V4.

Comment: I think I might be able to take some of your naming advice for this version though.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper yeah, the `queryString` variable name will cause confusion for those accustom to `?key=value` representing query strings in a URI

Comment: How about serialization? Do you think there's any point in making it task based?

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper my advice would be to experiment. Run some benchmarks for the synchronous and asynchronous and go with the better performing one. If the serialization is already wrapped in an async call it wont make much of a difference if the underlying serialization is actually synchronous.

Comment: seeing you've been so super nice, there's one more thing I want to ask. What about the namespace? I've currently put everything in RestClientDotNet. It's ugly. I'd prefer RestClient.Net but it conflicts with other important and related namespaces. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper what conflicts?

Comment: Oops sorry. Just tested this. It doesn't conflict with other namespaces. The problem is that the first part of the namespace is the same name as the class. So, that conflicts. The error is 'RestClient' is a namespace but is used like a type. I guess it's a product naming issue but too late to change now. @nkosi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102513/discussion-between-melbourne-developer-and-nkosi).

Comment: Thank you *so much for this detailed answer*. I like the idea of just using a `SendAsync` method that essentially has the same signature as most Http verbed actions, and to use extension methods to be more explicit in caller code.